# building an oracle with chainlink to POAO

Tags: api-key, chainlink

i just try to find out how to build an oracle on chainlink to the POAP-API. I get the impression there is something wrong in my approach. My Goal is to find out if an adress had mint the token of our poap-event IN A SMART-CONTRACT (which i build on my own.) The API of POAP give me all the informations an this works for my DAPP pretty good. But when i try to put the call in the contract - i get a problem with the api-key. As far as i understand - i have to build an NODE-OPERATOR but then i is really getting difficult. (from contract i call the chainlink-api and from there the operator and from there poap-api).

1. Question: is my understanding correct =
2. Any Example of a node-operator and where does it run ?
3. Is there a much easier way which i do not see at the moment ?

thanks for support an ideas !

Answer (score 1):

Chainlink community node operator here.

To answer your questions:

1. Your understanding of Chainlink's basic request model is correct.
2. Sure, we can serve this request (or any data available on the internet) for you through our existing oracle infrastructure. Feel free to check out the oracle / job documentation at LinkWell Nodes for example smart contracts and job IDs that will serve this data for you (disclaimer: I work for this company), and let me know if you have any questions.
3. There are indeed other ways to do this, such as using Chainlink Functions (involves coding up your request in JS), or reaching out to other existing node operators in the Chainlink Official Discord channel and posting your request to the #operator-requests channel.

Best of luck to you, and I hope that helps!

Comment: +1 to @Derek's answer.  I recommend that you look at [Chainlink Functions](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions) which would be much easier for you to test and iterate with.